# Non-static members not accessible in static function

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, static-methods, static-members

I have defined a function

```
HRESULT AMEPreviewHandler:: CreateHtmlPreview()
{
    ULONG  CbRead;
    const int Size= 115000;
    char Buffer[Size+1];
    HRESULT hr = m_pStream->Read(Buffer, Size, &CbRead ); 
    //this m_pStream is not accessible here even it is declared globally. the program is asking me to 
    // declare it static because this CreateHtmlPreview() function called 
    //inside the Static function (i mean here :-static CreateDialog\WM_Command\CreateHtmlPreview();)
    //but if i declare it static the two problems arised are 
    //(1.) It is not able to access the value of the m_pStream which is defined globally.
    //(2.)If i declare it static globally then there are so many other function which are using this
    // value of m_pStream are not able to access it because they are non static.  

}
```

It is declared static somewhere in my program like this:

```
static HRESULT CreateHtmlPreview(); //i have declared it static because i am calling this function from DialogProc function.If i dont create it static here it dont work

//The function CreateHtmlPreview() is called inside the DialogProc function like this-

BOOL CALLBACK AMEPreviewHandler::DialogProc(HWND m_hwndPreview, UINT Umsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{......
case WM_COMMAND:
{  
    int ctl = LOWORD(wParam);
    int event = HIWORD(wParam);

    if (ctl == IDC_PREVIOUS && event == BN_CLICKED ) 
    {                       
        CreateHtmlPreview(); //here i am calling the function
        return 0;
    }  
}
```

}

So what can be done to make the value of non static `m_pStream` accessible in the static `CreateHtmlPreview()` function definition ?

Comment: When I read the title, I was like - "yup - that's correct"...

Comment: The question should not be how to trick the language into exposing non-static data into static context, but how to fix your design

Comment: Why not pass an instance of a `AMEPreviewHandler` object to the `CreateHtmlPreview` function? Or make the function not static if you need to access non-static member variables.

Comment: Joachim its not possible to make it non static.. because if i do so  i wont be able to use CreateHtmlPreview() inside the static DialogProc function..is there any other way you know ?? have you understood my question properly ??

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT Static member functions and data members are class-specific, non-static ones are instance-specific. If your function needs to access instance-specific data, it must operate on an instance (either the implicit `this` or one passed in). So it must either be non-static or externally get access to the instance whose data it wants to operate on.

Comment: Then either you have to do as nijansen thinks and redesign your class, or find some way of storing the object so it can be fetched from your static methods.

Comment: Shall I suggest a small redesign hint? Wouldn't it be nice if you could make an object of HtmlPreview which encapsulates the m_pStream and implement non-static function Create() on that? So, instead of a more C-ish CreateHtmlPreview() you can make a more C++-ish HtmlPreview.Create() call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to avoid static or global variables in dialog functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601763/is-it-possible-to-avoid-static-or-global-variables-in-dialog-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you make `CreateHtmlPreview()` a free function? 

What if you make it just create an html preview (instead of also reading from a stream)?

```
void CreateHtmlPreview(const char * buffer, int size)
{
  //...
}
```

Then read the data from the proc, and call it in `DialogProc`

```
//...
m_pStream->Read(Buffer, Size, &CbRead ); 
CreateHtmlPreview(Buffer, Size);
```

You will probably need to make the function return the preview to be any use though.

You do say you need to make it

> static because i am calling this function from DialogProc function

however, the DialogProc is not static (in the code you have posted), so I don't see what the problem would be.

Comment: i dont know why i need to make DialogProc function static otherwise it is giving error here m_hwndPreview = CreateDialogParam( g_hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDIALOG), m_hwndParent,(DLGPROC)DialogProc, (LPARAM)this); that m_hwndPreview = CreateDialogParam( g_hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDIALOG), m_hwndParent,(DLGPROC)DialogProc, (LPARAM)this); conversion to DLGPROC not possible and when i do it static everything works fine

Comment: Show the actual code and the actual errors you get (and try having nothing static)

Comment: Because CreateDialogParam takes a pointer to a simple function, not a pointer to member-function of some class.

Comment: Then there are important details missing from the question

Comment: Should m_pStream member be unique or it should be common among all instances of AMEPreviewHandler?

Comment: Doctor love could you please seethis link i have written the code here on this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790479/dialogproc-function-asking-to-declare-it-self-static

Comment: Cool - that's more the essence of the problem

Answer (score 1):

In static class functions you can access to only static class members.

Comment: yes i know that but here in this situation i need to access the m_pStream which is non static ..and if i declare it static gloally the other non static members which are using this m_pStream will no more be able to access it

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pass the m_pStream var as a function argument?

Instead of defining the function this way

```
HRESULT AMEPreviewHandler:: CreateHtmlPreview()
{

    ULONG  CbRead;
    const int Size= 115000;
    char Buffer[Size+1];
    HRESULT hr = m_pStream->Read(Buffer, Size, &CbRead );

}
```

You can do it like this (you should define the stream type!)

```
HRESULT AMEPreviewHandler:: CreateHtmlPreview(stream)
{

    ULONG  CbRead;
    const int Size= 115000;
    char Buffer[Size+1];
    HRESULT hr = stream->Read(Buffer, Size, &CbRead );

}
```

And call it like this

```
CreateHtmlPreview(m_pStream);
```

Comment: No i can't do that because CreateHtmlPreview() is aclled from the DialogProc function which is also static... and its due to DialogProc i needed to make it static otherwise otherwise i am not intrested in creating problems to myself..is there any other solution you can purpose ??

Answer (score 0):

DoctorLove i have solved this problem actually the code by idea of accesing the non static varible using this parameter- the problem was i had not initialized the instance in WM_INITDIALOG now i donze like this-

```
case WM_INITDIALOG: 
            {

                instance = (AMEPreviewHandler*)lParam;
                instance->m_pStream;
return0;
}
```

and it works fine.