# DialogProc function asking to declare it self static

Tags: winapi, c++11, dialog, static-methods, static-members

here is my createdialogparam function which is calling DialogProc function from here-

```
 HRESULT AMEPreviewHandler::CreatePreviewWindow()
    {
        assert(m_hwndPreview == NULL);
        assert(m_hwndParent != NULL);
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        m_hwndPreview = CreateDialogParam( g_hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDIALOG), m_hwndParent,(DLGPROC)DialogProc, (LPARAM)this); /here the dialog proc function is called
        if (m_hwndPreview == NULL)
        {
          hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
    ..........
    ...
    }
```

here is the definition of DialogProc function-

```
BOOL CALLBACK AMEPreviewHandler::DialogProc(HWND m_hwndPreview, UINT Umsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
    { 
        static RECT m_rcParent ;

        switch(Umsg)
        {
        case WM_INITDIALOG: 
            {
            return 0;
            }
            break;
........
case WM_COMMAND:
            {  
                int ctl = LOWORD(wParam);
                int event = HIWORD(wParam);

                if (ctl == IDC_PREVIOUS && event == BN_CLICKED ) 
                {         

                    CreateHtmlPreview(); //it must be static now and it is not able to access the non static vraibles delared globally in the program
                    return 0;
                }     
}
}
```

and the declaration is like this-

static  BOOL CALLBACK  DialogProc(HWND hWindow, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); //suppose it is static ..it is not giving any error if static ..If it is not declared static it gives error
here -

```
m_hwndPreview = CreateDialogParam( g_hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDIALOG), m_hwndParent,(DLGPROC)DialogProc, (LPARAM)this); //error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'DLGPROC'
```

Is there any way to access the globally declared variables inside the  static DialogProc or it is possible to access the globally declared variables inside the dialogproc without declaring the  those variables as static because t hey are also used as non static in other part of program ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by

> globally declared variables inside the static DialogProc

you mean member variables in an instance of `AMEPreviewHandler`, I think you have sent what you need in the LPARAM:

```
m_hwndPreview = CreateDialogParam( ...(LPARAM)this);
```

When it calls your DialogProc these go to the last parameter: `LPARAM lParam` so you can do

```
AMEPreviewHandler* instance = (AMEPreviewHandler *)lParam;
instance->m_Whatever...
```

Comment: you mean i need to pass m_pStream as last parameter in function -m_hwndPreview = CreateDialogParam( ...(LPARAM)this); then i would be able to access it inside the DialogProc function

Comment: Send this as you are, then use instance->m_pStream with instance defined as in my answer

Comment: but when i do this AMEPreviewHandler* instance = (AMEPreviewHandler)lParam;
  instance->m_pStream; //i get an error error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'LPARAM' to 'AMEPreviewHandler'

Comment: I missed a * - you sent "this" which is a pointer

Comment: but it still has the problem on debugging-(AMEShellExtPreviewHandlerFinal.dll) in prevhost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000030. at line  when i debug  (instance->m_pStream)->Read(Buffer, Size, &CbRead ); inside DialogProc function..when i put the cursor on instance it shows m_pstream= ????

Comment: OK time for a new question, showing how you initialise m_pstream

Comment: AMEPreviewHandler::AMEPreviewHandler() : m_cRef(1), m_pStream(NULL) //here it is, m_hwndParent(NULL), m_hwndPreview(NULL), m_punkSite(NULL),hwndButton(NULL) { InterlockedIncrement(&g_cDllRef); m_iFinalWidth=0; m_iFinalHeight=0; HeightOfImage = 0; WidthOfImage=0; char * FileContents=0; refMsg = 0; }

Comment: IFACEMETHODIMP AMEPreviewHandler::Initialize(IStream *pStream, DWORD grfMode)
{
   HRESULT hr = E_INVALIDARG;
   if (pStream)
   {
      // Initialize can be called more than once, so release existing valid 
      // m_pStream.
      if (m_pStream)
      {
         m_pStream->Release();
         m_pStream = NULL;
      }

      m_pStream = pStream;
      m_pStream->AddRef();

      // Clean up the allocated resources in a centralized place.
      if (m_AMEHBitmap)
      {
         DeleteObject(m_AMEHBitmap);
         m_AMEHBitmap = NULL;
      }

      hr = S_OK;
   }
   return hr;
}