# Is there any way to make the DialogProc work without declaring as Nonstatic

Tags: winapi, button, dialog, static-methods, static-members

I have developed any button application using createDialogParam and DialogProc. first i declared  DialoProc method as static in order to make every thing work fine and it  worked but now the situation is that there are so many variables(Not globally declared) and functions which i have to use inside DialogProc function and now i want to make it Non static because making it static makes me not implement few more things.

If i don't declare it static it gives error

```
    m_hwndPreview = CreateDialogParam( g_hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDIALOG), m_hwndParent,(DLGPROC)DialogProc, (LPARAM)this);  //('type cast' cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' 
//to 'DLGPROC')
```

Is there any solution to make dialogProc function without declaring it static ???

Answer (score 0):

It must be a static function because Windows calls it from C code, not C++ code. But there are several ways your static function can retrieve a 'this' pointer that you saved somewhere, then use that pointer to call a class member function. Every GUI library available for Windows solves this problem: Consider using one.

Comment: actually i am doing the same but i have problem on debuging Unhandled exception at 0x000007fef535203c (AMEShellExtPreviewHandlerFinal.dll) in prevhost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000030. for more info you can see this question on this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789402/non-static-members-not-accessible-in-static-function

Comment: actually what i have to access inside the DialogPros is stream (created by clicking on preview handler file in order to store its contents in buffer and i am not able to access tthat stream variable m_pStream inside DialogProc)... i am doing like this -AMEPreviewHandler* instance = (AMEPreviewHandler*)lParam;
  instance->m_pStream;